# Linux MD RAID resilience in situations with unpredictable power

Tags: linux, software-raid

If you were given a situation where you **MUST** use RAID for reasons outside of your control and the server with the RAID may not be on a battery backup *and* the building is prone to power loss, what are some things you can do to make the RAID more resilient in situations where the power is killed immediately? This situation sounds contrived but it is actually a situation I am in right now for reasons I can't go into.

Would any specific RAID specification supported by Linux software RAID be any more resilient in dealing with power loss than any other RAID spec or are there any RAID configuration parameters that might be helpful here?

For example, is a RAID 10 more/less prone to not coming back after power loss than, say, a parity-based RAID configuration like RAID5 or RAID6. Additionally, are there any RAID configuration settings that attempt to deal with the reality of not having a nice hardware RAID BBU to cache writes?

Comment: I would walk away... [***NOPE...NOPE...NOPE***](http://static4.fjcdn.com/comments/godzilla+s+fw+japanese+hornets+_cc6d4636480771f463eab300a880241a.png)

Comment: Run.  Even without raid unstable power will eventually cause data loss.  RAID will make it even more difficult to recover and add an extra layer where things can go wrong. UPSs are cheap compared to losing all your work.

Comment: Change all your mount points to `sync`, disable write caching, and buy a UPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't remember any md raid specific options however:

**Disable disk write cache**

```
hdparm
 -W   get/set drive write-caching flag (0/1)
```

**mount all partitions with the sync/dirsync options**

from man mount:

```
dirsync  
All directory updates within the file system should be done synchronously.  This affects the   following sys-tem calls: creat, link, unlink, symlink, mkdir, rmdir, mknod and rename.

sync  
All I/O to the file system should be done synchronously. In case of media  with  limited  number   of  write cycles (e.g. some flash drives) "sync" may cause life-cycle shortening.
```

... and maybe after a power loss it will be in sync.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you can do which will help, which TomTom and Barlomiej covered.  But this is still a bad idea.  The real solution is that **someone's requirements need to change**.  So I'm going to give you a bunch of reasons why this is a bad idea, which you can take to whoever thought these requirements were acceptable.

Setting RAID aside for a moment, having the power cut from a server unexpectedly will eventually cause problems:

- If power loss is common in the building, unstable power may be as well - brownout and overvoltage conditions can take a big toll on the hardware and significantly reduce it's lifespan.
- You'll lose whatever you were working on when the server crashes.  Even if the filesystem itself is fine, what happens to the files it was half way through saving over when the power was cut?  In some cases, you not only lose the work you were just saving, but the entire file is corrupt and lose all the work before it.
- Eventually, your filesystem will get corrupted.  Modern filesystems typically handle this fairly well, though you may spend extra time checking the filesystems when the power comes back up.  On large disks, this can take hours.  Sometimes days.  Even if the users of this server can tolerate it rebooting when the power goes out, they are unlikely to tolerate it being out for an additional 4 hours after the power comes back.
- Even with write caching disabled, you will still lose some data.  It significantly reduces the risk, but doesn't avoid it altogether.
- One day, your filesystem will be corrupted, and fsck won't fix it.  Then you get to restore from backups.  Then you realize the backups are corrupted due to the same power issues.

Now throw RAID into the mix:

- Adding another layer of storage where data can be corrupted - at the filesystem, RAID, and the disks themselves.
- So, one of your disks gets damaged when the power fails.  No problem.  That's what RAID is for.  Throw a new disk in the server and it starts rebuilding.  Rebuilding takes hours or days on most systems.  While it's busy rebuilding, performance is terrible, but at least the system is still up.  Then the power goes out again.  Depending on the RAID it may start over resyncing, or it may start where it left off.  But the worst case scenario is the power loss causes a second disk to fail.  Or a third.  And now the RAID array is unrecoverable.

UPSs exist for a reason.  You don't need a fancy server rack sized UPS.  If you have to, you could probably get away with a higher end consumer UPS for about $100-200.  All you really need is for it to last long enough to properly power down the server.  Connect the USB cable, setup the UPS software, and set it so the computer starts shutting down after 10 seconds of power loss.  Now it stays up during the small half second power outages (and the UPS makes sure the server doesn't see any of the horrible power conditions that usually go along with such events).  And during the longers one it shuts down nice and orderly, no data lost, no working a 20 hours shift trying to get the server back up.

If you give us more information on why these requirements exist, we can give you more ideas on how to work within the spirit of the requirement and come up with an acceptable solution.  But as it says now, all I can say is:  **Get a UPS.**

Answer (score 0):

Start by using a write cache SSD - and get one with condensators to handle the power loss.

Otherwise make sure you disable any performance tip. No write back caching anywhere in the stack (including hardware level).

And that is about it. Not sure linux has a file system optimized for this.

Comment: Can you configure software RAID to use a write cache SSD?  I thought that was something you'd need a hardware controller for.

Comment: Read up on ZFS.

Comment: Can be done with bcache.